# Non EU citizen working for Austrian company in Austria and has main residence in Germany

Tags: eu-spouses, working, tax-treaties, non-citizens

Well, my situation is a bit different from others and would like to know how I could keep my job. I have a Rot-Weiss Rot plus visa from Austria and I am moving to Germany soon. (My husband is EU citizen.)
I will change my main residence from Asutria to Germany. That means my Austrian Visa is no longer.

I would like to keep my job with home office in Berlin.
As long as I don't have registered residence in Vienna, my company cannot pay my salary I belive.

Is it possible the Austiran compny pay for me all taxes (social, health insurance, etc.) to Germany? What kind of things should my compan prepare for that ?

I should give some suggestions to my company how they could handle this issue. I cannot find proper information for it.
That would be appreciated if I could have some info here.

(For registration in Germany as freelancer, that means I should pay all taxes myself. My Salary is not that higher enough)

Comment: Whereabouts in Germany are you moving?  I live in Baden-Württemberg close to the border with Switzerland.  _Lots_ of people around here go to work in Switzerland every day, and I used to commute to Switzerland weekly.  The term for this is _Grenzgängerin_.  I paid health insurance in CH, but I was also able to register with a German Krankenkasse so I could receive treatment in DE.  I paid something like 4% income tax in CH plus social insurance, and then filled out a normal tax return in DE with the 4% offset against my tax liability.  I now have a small Swiss pension as a result.

Comment: Oh.  Re-reading you are moving to Berlin.  I suspect Grenzgänger is not going to be possible for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Well, my situation is a bit different from others and would like to know how I could keep my job. I have a Rot-Weiss Rot plus visa from Austria and I am moving to Germany soon (my husband is EU citizen). I will change my main residence from Austria to Germany. That means my Austrian Visa is no longer.

The fact your husband is an EU citizen makes a big difference. It's important that you get a German visa as the spouse of an EU citizen. It means you can work there without conditions and do not need to rely on your job and your employer to sort out your immigration situation.

> I would like to keep my job with home office in Berlin. As long as I don't have registered residence in Vienna, my company cannot pay my salary I believe. Is it possible the Austrian compny pay for me all taxes (social, health insurance, etc.) to Germany? What kind of things should my company prepare for that?

It's not trivial. You are essentially in the same situation as a German or EU citizen who works remotely for that company. The main solutions I have seen in that situation are:

- Find a local entity to run payroll. If your “real” employer does not any presence in Germany, they can pay an “employer of record” or global “payroll provider” to do it for them. That company will obviously charge a fee on top of your salary and all applicable taxes and contriutions.
- You register yourself as freelance and become a contractor rather than an employee. You have to figure out all the details yourself and should charge accordingly.

> For registration in Germnay as freelancer, that means I should pay all taxes myself. My Salary is not that higher enough.

If you become a contractor, you should expect the company to pay more, precisely because you have to shoulder a lot of costs and they don't (right now you cost them more than your salary). It makes no sense to become a contractor and charge exactly the same amount an employee would get as a salary. Whether you can charge them that much more that you're not losing out is another question (beyond health insurance, you also have to think about leave days or retirement).

Comment: Thanks! It was  good to know it " payroll provider" . To use " payroll provider " or  " to have    salary before tax as a freelancer "     Should I  register in Germany as a freelancer

Comment: Should I register in Germany as  a freelancer additionally  or is it enough  to do with my normal german Visa if I took the 2nd option ? Well I should get the Salary before tax deduction( not the net income) from company. Hum.

Comment: @Hannah as a contractor you should expect _more than your current gross salary,_ because you have more expenses than you would as an employee, and your company should agree to this because _they currently pay more to employ you than your current gross salary,_ specifically for payroll taxes and other benefits (insurance, health benefits, etc.; I don't know precisely what these are in Austria).  Whether you can negotiate a mutually agreeable figure is of course another question, but if the deal is cost neutral to the company, the gross figure will increase.  The net figure might not.

Comment: @Hannah What do you mean by “register as a freelancer” and why do you think this is connected to the visa? You don't necessarily need a specific visa but you should expect some formalities.